# mkdir system call with variable (C)

Tags: c, linux, mkdir

I'm new to Linux system programming. The task is: create system variable "MY_DIR" with valuable "lab01" and create any file inside it.

I've successfully created folder, but I can't create any file using varialble

```
putenv("MY_DIR=lab01");
mkdir_ret_code = mkdir(("/home/Alexander/%s",getenv("MY_DIR")),0777);
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you've tagged this question as "c" but std::string is C++...

Comment: oh, sorry, of course I want pure C

Comment: It seems strange to hardcode the prefix `/home/Alexander/`. Why not just leave that off, so `mkdir(getenv("MY_DIR"),...)` and run the program from the correct directory. Note that for security you should probably do some checks on MY_DIR before you use it.

Comment: That's just for training purpose, I know that using hardcoded things isn't very nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array and use these functions http://linux.die.net/man/3/string